# How to append prefix to all url names when using include function - django

Tags: python, django

I want to include some django app's urls, in two different parent routes. The problem is, if I try to do this, then I will not be able to use `reverse` function properly for that app's urls.

This is where I'm stuck. The following url configurations will result in creation of two different url sets, e.g:

```
/api/v4/auth/{login, register, ...}
/api/auth/{login, register, ...}
```

app A (urls.py)

```py
from auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^register/', views.register, name='register'),
    ...
]
```

main app (urls.py)

```py
from auth import urls as auth_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v4/auth/', include(auth_urls)),
    url(r'^api/auth/', include(auth_urls)),
    ...
]
```

Now, if I try to use `reverse` function like below:

```py
def get_login_url():
    return reverse('login')
```

I would probably get one of the possible outputs which I don't know how to control!

I don't know if django supports appending some kind of prefix to names of the urls that are being included or is there any tricks to hack around it or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)

```
from auth import urls as auth_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v4/auth/', include(auth_urls, namespace='auth1'))),
    url(r'^api/auth/', include(auth_urls, namespace='auth2'))),
    ...
]
```

This way, you will be able to reverse alling `auth1:login`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was sure there is a way around it. Solved my problem ;)